# PHP list array and get value

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have some difficulties with PHP Arrays. I'm trying to foreach some values, order them with array_multisort and foreach them again so I can create some kind of code.
So what I'm doing is, I'm passing json object as:

```
"options": [
                    {"key": "Ships From", "value": "Russia"},
                    {"key": "Color", "value": "Green"},
                    {"key": "Size", "value": "M"},
                    {"key": "Material", "value": "Flex"}
                   
            ],
```

So this is received from frontend, and I'm foreaching them like so:

```
public function findAttribute($product_id, $values)
    {
            $array = array();
            
            foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
                $getAttr = $this->attribute($value['key']);
    
                $getAttrValue = $this->attributeValue($getAttr->id, $value['value']);
    
                $code = $getAttr['label'] . '=' . $getAttrValue['value'];
                $collection = array_push($array, array($getAttr->default_order, $code));
            }
    
            array_multisort($array, SORT_ASC);
}
```

As you can see I have `$getAttr` and `$getAttrValue`, that selects values from database, in order to get default_order (integer) so I can sort them with  `multisort`.
So actually this code works as expected, and when I write (after multisort) like:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
            echo $value[1] .'/';
        }
```

I have expected value, but when I call that function it gives me that it returns `NULL`, if I change echo to return, I have only first array. If I try like

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
            $code = $value[1] .'/';
}
return $code;
```

No success as well.
What should I do?

Comment: Have you look at PHP methods `array_search` ?

Answer (score 1):

Because in each iteration you assign a new value to `$code` so you will only get the last `$value [1]` in the `array` (after arranged).
If you want to return a string concatenating all values, you could do as this:

```php
$code = '';
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $code .= $value[1] .'/';
}
return $code;
```

Comment: @somebodytolove You are welcome! If you find my answer to be correct and helpful, please mark it as correct and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$code = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value){
        $code = $value[$key] .'/';
}
return $code;
```

Implement your code i hope that will work.